# Is the thermal expansion of steel negligible at small scales?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, physical-chemistry

My lab is testing heat resistance of endospores with an oil bath.  Spore suspension is held in heat-sealed glass capillary tubes (100uL internal volume, ~5cm long as I recall, relatively fragile) which we plan to bundle in fours with steel wire scavenged from bread ties (we are poorly funded) and suspend in oil from a ring stand.  We will be heating the oil to a maximum of 130C for 5 minutes before transferring tube bundles to an ice bath.  Is the thermal expansion of steel significant enough for the wire to loosen under heat, dropping the tubes, or contract upon cooling, crushing them?

Thanks!

Love,
A microbio undergrad

Answer (score 0):

The coefficient of expansion for steel is approximately $13\,\rm ppm\, ^\circ C^{-1}$, for Pyrex $4\,\rm ppm\, ^\circ C^{-1}$, and for glass $9\,\rm ppm\, ^\circ C^{-1}$.

The steel will expand more than the Pyrex/glass so I suggest some sort of bottom to the steel "cage".

*. . . . . contract upon cooling, crushing them.*
The materials will eventually return to their original sizes although because it has a larger thermal conductivity and the surface is more exposed the steel will do so before the Pyrex/glass but if there is a bottom to the cage that should be no problem.